# Getting DML limit error in apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

I have a batch class which runs to delete old records, which in turn triggers a trigger on before delete.
Now when the trigger runs it hits dml limit as calling class dml statements is running inside loop.

Can anyone help how to resolve this issue.

Below is the class and trigger -

Trigger -

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on X_Opportunity__c (before delete) 
{

        for (X_Opportunity__c o : Trigger.old)
        {
            OpportunityMethods.opportunityDeleted(o);
        }

}
```

Class -

```
public class OpportunityMethods
{

public static void opportunityDeleted(X_Opportunity__c o)
    {
        deleteOpportunityAccounts(o);
        deleteOpportunitySalesTeams(o);
        deleteOpportunityLineItems(o);
    }


private static void deleteOpportunityAccounts(X_Opportunity__c o)
    {
        List<X_Opportunity_Account__c> opportunityAccounts = getOpportunityAccounts(o);
        delete opportunityAccounts;
    }

private static void deleteOpportunitySalesTeams(X_Opportunity__c o)
    {
        List<X_Opportunity_Sales_Team__c> salesTeams = getOpportunitySalesTeams(o);
        delete salesTeams;
    }
    private static void deleteOpportunityLineItems(X_Opportunity__c o)
    {
        List<X_Opportunity_Line_Item__c> opportunityLineItems = getOpportunityLineItems(o);
        delete opportunityLineItems;
    }
private static List<X_Opportunity_Account__c> getOpportunityAccounts(X_Opportunity__c o)
    {
        List<X_Opportunity_Account__c> opportunityAccounts =
                [select Id, Account__c, Advertiser__c, Agency__c, Close_Date__c, 
                        Opportunity__c, Stage__c, Total_Amount__c
                 from   X_Opportunity_Account__c
                 where  Opportunity__c = :o.Id];

        return opportunityAccounts;
    }
private static List<X_Opportunity_Sales_Team__c> getOpportunitySalesTeams(X_Opportunity__c o)
    {
        List<X_Opportunity_Sales_Team__c> salesTeams =
               [select Id, Opportunity__c, Sales_Rep__c, Split_Percent__c, OwnerId
                from   X_Opportunity_Sales_Team__c
                where  Opportunity__c = :o.Id];

        if (salesTeams == null || salesTeams.size() == 0)
        {

            salesTeams = new List<X_Opportunity_Sales_Team__c>();
            X_Opportunity_Sales_Team__c ost = new X_Opportunity_Sales_Team__c();
            ost.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
            ost.Sales_Rep__c = o.OwnerId;
            ost.OwnerId = o.OwnerId;
            ost.Split_Percent__c = 100.00;

            insert ost;

            salesTeams.add(ost);
        }               
        return salesTeams;
    }
private static List<X_Opportunity_Line_Item__c> getOpportunityLineItems(X_Opportunity__c o)
    {
        List<X_Opportunity_Line_Item__c> opportunityLineItems =
                [select Id, Opportunity__c, Product__c, Product_Amount__c, Sales_Rep__c, OwnerId
                 from   X_Opportunity_Line_Item__c
                 where  Opportunity__c = :o.Id];

        return opportunityLineItems;
    }   


}
```

Comment: Is this still an open question? Please accept answers when they resolve your issue. You have only accepted answers to 26% of your answers. Surely you have resolved more than one issue in four.

Answer (score 4):

You need builkify your trigger as @manjit_singh and @pnoytechie said.

**Your Trigger bulkfied:**

```
    trigger OpportunityTrigger on X_Opportunity__c (before delete) 
{
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        Set<String> oppids = Trigger.oldMap.keySet();
        delete [SELECT ID FROM X_Opportunity_Account__c WHERE Opportunity__c  in : oppIds];
        delete [SELECT ID FROM X_Opportunity_Sales_Team__c WHERE Opportunity__c  in : oppIds];
        delete [SELECT ID FROM X_Opportunity_Line_Item__c WHERE Opportunity__c  in : oppIds];
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You Apex trigger and class code is not bulkified hence you are receiving this error.

You are also querying inside a for loop that too three times for a single iteration.

Try to bulkify your class by taking List as an argument and do not call the class method in the for Loop in the trigger.

Here are the best practices. You need to implement the first three:

[Best Practices Salesforce Apex Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

Answer (score -1):

you need to bulkify. old-style programming doesn't always work with salesforce. here's a (untested) sample based on your code above:

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on X_Opportunity__c (before delete) 
{
        List<sObject> recsToDelete = new List<sObject>();
        for (X_Opportunity__c o : Trigger.old)
        {
            recsToDelete.addAll((List<sObject>) OpportunityMethods.getOpportunityAccounts(o));
            recsToDelete.addAll((List<sObject>) OpportunityMethods.getOpportunitySalesTeams(o));
            recsToDelete.addAll((List<sObject>) OpportunityMethods.getOpportunityAccounts(o));
        }
        if (recsToDelete.size()>10000) {
            //you would want to execute by batch since it is more than the allowable DML rows
        } else {
            if (recsToDelete.size())>0 delete recsToDelete;
        }
}
```

Comment: This code sample you gave here is not bulkified either.  You are doing queries inside of loops.

Comment: Hi pnoytechie.. I am getting the "Error: Compile Error: Only concrete SObject lists can be created at line 125 column 38" error at line "List<sObject> recsToDelete = new List<sObject>();".. Can u help..

Comment: Is there any way to merge all the methods into a single list and then delete it

Comment: Hi Sid, i can execute `List<sObject> recsToDelete = new List<sObject>();` without any error.

but as dphil pointed out, the code I posted is not bulkified.